# ios tableview + screenshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, modal-dialog

I'm using RNBlurModalView (https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView) to blur the background of my modal view. The problem is that when I scroll my table view the screenshot does not scroll as well. As you scroll, the blur eventually disappears. I know I need to use the content offset of the table view, but am not sure how to implement it in the existing code

```
RNBlurModalView.m

#pragma mark - UIView + Screenshot

@implementation UIView (Screenshot)

- (UIImage*)screenshot {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // hack, helps w/ our colors when blurring
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1); // convert to jpeg
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return image;
}

@end
```

And my code for implementing the view

```
- (IBAction)locationPressed:(id)sender {

   UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [self storyboard];
    HomeViewController *homeView  = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:@"Hello world!" message:@"Pur your message here."];
    [modal show];


    [self presentPopupViewController:homeView animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you present the blurred view? I think the problem is you're adding it to the UITableView, so it's acting as header.

Comment: edited the question to provide you with that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I thought the problem is that when you call `[[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:@"Hello world!" message:@"Pur your message here."];` the method adds itself to the given controller's view:

```
- (id)initWithViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController view:(UIView*)view {
    if (self = [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewController.view.width, viewController.view.height)]) {
        [self addSubview:view];
...
}
```

So another problem is that using UITableViewController is OK when you only have a simple table, but it doesn't work so good when you want to add other views, so try this:

Modify your viewDidLoad to look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create a new view to lay underneath the UITableView
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    view.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
    // add the uiTableView as a subview
    [view addSubview:self.tableView];
    self.view = view;
    self.tableView.frame = view.bounds;
}
```

It's creating a UIView and putting it beneath the UITableView.

The next time you need more than just the regular UITableView consider using a UIViewController, with a UITableView as subview instead.